# How to set background image for custom radio button android with original scale ratio?

Tags: android, background, radio-button, scale, android-button

I need to implement a timeline bar as attached image

> [image]

I try to use custom radio button to draw each node:
**layout xml** file:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    >
    <RadioGroup 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:checkedButton="@+id/first">
       <RadioButton android:id="@+id/first"
          style="@style/timeLineRadioButton"/>
       <RadioButton android:id="@+id/second"
          style="@style/timeLineRadioButton"/>
       <RadioButton android:id="@+id/third"
          style="@style/timeLineRadioButton"/>
       <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fourth"
          style="@style/timeLineRadioButton"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**res/values/style.xml**:

```
<style name="timeLineRadioButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top|center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_radio</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">matrix</item>
</style>
```

**res/drawable/button_radio.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_pressed"/>
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button"/>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_pressed"/>
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button"/>
</selector>
```

The timeline display ok, but background was scale with different ratio 
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5860710/timeline.jpg]

so, please help me to fix background image with original ratio scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, I guess you want to achieve something like `scaleType="center"` of ImageView, but unfortunately, there is no thing like that for `RadioButton`, but I think this solution may help you.

First, don't use `weightSum/layout_weight` in this case, just set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for RadioButtons.

Seconds, update your selector like this (note that the main point is using of `bitmap` tag that has `gravity` property, and this code I set it to `center`)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/radio_button_pressed" android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/radio_button" android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/radio_button_pressed" android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/radio_button" android:gravity="center" />
  </item>
</selector>
```

So the result is your RadioButton's background will behave like `scaleType="center"`

Hope this helps!